# change words just once in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to find and replace `@jo` for `@josh` in a text.

My problem is, If I keep clicking on span the output become something like this:

```
@joshshsh
```

js

```
$(document).on("click", ".cclass", function() {

var p = '@jo';
var username = '@josh';

$("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(p, username)); //want to replace @jo to @josh just once

});
```

any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/pL6ut0ac/

Comment: remove the click event when you finished replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

With a regex:

```
$(document).on("click", ".cclass", function() {
    var p = new RegExp("@jo\\b");
    var username = '@josh';
    $("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(p, username)); //want to replace @jo to @josh just once
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lfgkn2rg/)**

Or just by adding a space

```
$(document).on("click", ".cclass", function() {
    var p = '@jo ';
    var username = '@josh ';
    $("#comment").val($("#comment").val().replace(p, username)); //want to replace @jo to @josh just once
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1tp9j9ha/1/)**

Comment: Why the double-backslash in front of the `@`?

Comment: @JohnHascall - You need to escape the slash from the backslashes.

Comment: Let me rephrase -- why does `@` need a backslash in front of it.  Seems to me that `RegExp("@jo\\b");` would work just as well.

Comment: @JohnHascall - gah, you're right. For some reason I was thinking `@` was a special character. Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the power of a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), here using `\b` as a word boundary:
Just change:

```
var p = '@jo';
```

to:

```
var p = /@jo\b/;
```

And it will only replace `@jo` where it is followed by some "non-word" character, like:
(`@jo,@anna` `@jo @anna`, but not `@josh`).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the .on method with the .one.

```
$(document).one("click", ".cclass", function() { /**/ });
```

the one method will fire the bound event only once.

link here: https://jsfiddle.net/pL6ut0ac/1/

Edit:

you can use .data method to set arbitrary data on the clicked element

```
$(this).data('paramName', paramValue);
```

link: https://jsfiddle.net/pL6ut0ac/4/

Comment: oh, .one is nice but I want to use the function for other nicks after this. jo and josh is only an example, I will get this values from different spans for different users.